# objdump is missing from windows10 pro (msys2 installed)

Tags: mingw-w64, msys2, gnuwin32

I have installed msys2 using chocolatey.
I have tried msys2-installer module from chocolatey too. 
But I can not find objdump on my system. Should I install something more ?

Answer (score 1):

MSYS2 supports three different compiler toolchains, all with their own objdump utility.  I'm not sure which one you want to use, but you can just install them all by running:

```
sudo pacman -S binutils mingw-w64-x86_64-binutils mingw-w64-i686-binutils
```

Comment: I am not sure either but I can check with the guy who needs it. I want the correct one in PATH